# JPA - How to query by joined entities?

Tags: spring, jpa, kotlin

I wrote the following Query to use in a Spring JpaRespository:

```
private const val SEARCH  =
                "SELECT vf " + 
                "FROM VideoFile vf " +
                "LEFT JOIN vf.stars st " +
                "LEFT JOIN vf.categories c " +
                "LEFT JOIN vf.series se " +
                "WHERE (:searchText IS NULL OR (" +
                "vf.fileName LIKE :searchText OR vf.displayName LIKE :searchText OR vf.description LIKE :searchText)) " +
                "AND (:seriesId IS NULL OR se.seriesId = :seriesId) " +
                "AND (:starId IS NULL OR st.starId = :starId) " +
                "AND (:categoryId IS NULL OR c.categoryId = :categoryId)"
```

This is based on a SQL query I had tested previously, but written to use JPQL. I'm going to include my entity (Kotlin) below so what I'm going to explain will make more sense:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "video_files")
data class VideoFile(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        var fileId: Long = 0,
        @Column(unique = true)
        var fileName: String = "",
        var displayName: String = "",
        var description: String = "",
        var lastModified: LocalDateTime = DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP,
        @JsonIgnore
        var lastScanTimestamp: LocalDateTime = DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP,
        @Column(columnDefinition = "int default 0")
        var viewCount: Int = 0,

        @ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "file_categories",
                joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "file_id")],
                inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "category_id")])
        var categories: Set<Category> = HashSet(),

        @ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "file_series",
                joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "file_id")],
                inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "series_id")])
        var series: Set<Series> = HashSet(),

        @ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "file_stars",
                joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "file_id")],
                inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "star_id")])
        var stars: Set<Star> = HashSet()
)
```

So, my VideoFile entity has a ManyToMany relationship with the Category, Series, and Star entities. The query I'm writing is an attempt to get all VideoFiles that are joined with certain categories, series, stars, etc.

The query I have right now is returning duplicate records, I believe because of the LEFT JOINS. Because the VideoFile matches with multiple Categories, I get the same record returned multiple times.

I'm good with SQL, I'm still a novice at JPQL. I would appreciate some help refactoring this so that it just filters the VideoFiles by the joined entities, rather than returning the extra records.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, checking for "nullability" of a passed variable inside the query is probably not a good idea and to be honest I don't know if JPQL supports something like that.

Also, since you are using JPQL, make sure you are going to execute that query as a JPQL query and you won't need the to join the entities (at least not for a simple left join), since they are already related in the Model.

So your query should look like this:

```
private const val SEARCH  =
                "SELECT vf " + 
                "FROM VideoFile vf " +
                "WHERE (vf.categories.id =:categoryId) " +
                "AND (vf.fileName LIKE :searchText OR vf.displayName LIKE :searchText OR vf.description LIKE :searchText) " +
                "AND (vf.series.id = :seriesId)  " +
                "AND (vf.stars.id = :starId) "
```

Just make sure that the id property in categories entity is named as "id".
Similarly make sure that the name property in categories in named as "name", etc... you get the idea.

Finally, you should try a different aproach with nulls, for example, I guess you won't ever need to check the id property of an entity for nulls.

So, one way to do this is to use a StringBuilder and check on Java/Kotlin level if the parameter is null and if it is, and also you are sure you want to get null entries of a field, you add an extra string to the builder with i.e. `OR vf.categories.name IS NULL`